# Как сделать кнопку restart в телеграмм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Делаю телеграмм бота на Python через библиотеку Aiogram. Добавил в меню бота кнопку restart, чтобы при нажатии бот перезагружался, если, например, возникает ошибка, долго отвечает итп. Но не знаю как её реализовать и сделать.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под "перезагружался"? Обычно, для перехода в начало используется команда /start

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от системы, на которой запущен ваш бот. В Unix-системах можете воспользоваться `subprocess`. Пример такой команды для `aiogram-3.x`:

```
@router.message(Command("restart"))
async def restart(message: types.Message):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["sudo", "systemctl", "restart", "telegram-bot"])
    await message.answer("Ушел на перезагрузку")
```

где `telegram-bot` - процесс, под которым запущен ваш бот/сервис